# NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, maven, dockerfile

I am building my application on java docker image.
java8 image builds the application but when I use java11, I get an error that JAVA_HOME variable should point to JDK and not JRE

When I checked the docker file, it does have any occurrence of JRE, please find below the docker file for reference.

```
# Set java enviroment
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=11 \
    JAVA_MINOR_VERSION=0 \
    JAVA_UPDATE=1 \
    JAVA_BUILD=13 \
    JAVA_PATH=90cf5d8f270a4347a95050320eef3fb7 \
    JAVA_TYPE=jdk

ENV JAVA_FULL_VERSION="${JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION}.${JAVA_MINOR_VERSION}.${JAVA_UPDATE}"

ENV JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/${JAVA_TYPE}-${JAVA_FULL_VERSION}" \
    JAVA_TAR="${JAVA_TYPE}-${JAVA_FULL_VERSION}_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz"

# Downloading oracle jdk -> extract it -> cleanup -> add app user & group
# You can use USER called 'app' for your application
RUN cd /tmp \
    && mkdir -p $JAVA_HOME 
    
    RUN curl  -u ****:**** https://artifactory/DockerSoftware/jdk-11.0.11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz  -o ${JAVA_TAR} 
    RUN ls -lrt
    RUN tar -xzf $JAVA_TAR -C /opt/java \
    && ln -s $JAVA_HOME $JAVA_HOME/bin/* /usr/bin/ \
    && rm -rf $JAVA_HOME/lib/src.zip \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/missioncontrol \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/*javafx* \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/*jfx* \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/*awt* \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/desktop \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/javaws.jar \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/plugin.jar \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/plugin-legacy.jar \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/javaws.jar \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/desktop \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/deploy \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/deploy* \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/fonts \
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/oblique-fonts \
    $JAVA_HOME/jmods \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
    && useradd -ms /bin/bash app

# Add java to path
ENV PATH /opt/java/jdk-11.0.11/bin:$PATH
```

Can someone help me understand when JAVA_TYPE mentioned is JDK, where is JRE coming from?

Comment: */opt/java/jdk-11.0.11/bin* is that valid? How are you starting the run?

Comment: There basically is no more JRE since Java 9. Possibly you're using something that determines if something is a JDK or JRE by the presence or absence of certain files (e.g. `tools.jar`), but this changed radically with Java 9 (e.g. `tools.jar` no longer exists since that version), so it is possible you're using something that does the detection incorrectly for Java 9 or higher.

Comment: If all else fails (e.g. inspecting what's happening with `ps` or `pgrep` and the like), then the fine-grained `strace` will show you what's being invoked. Save the log and look at the `execve` calls

Comment: @g00se I have a jenkins pipeline which builds an application. That app is using this docker image